# How can I create a symbolic link?

Tags: command-line

Symbolic links are useful for storing things in a separate place from where they appear to be.

> In computing, a symbolic link is a type of file that contains a reference to another file or directory. This affects pathname resolution.

How can I create one in elementary (both GUI/Terminal)?

Comment: I can't edit due to the lack of six characters for me to put in... but it's elementary, not Elementary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The latest version of Pantheon Files on freya allow you to drag and drop files by right-clicking on them.

When you drop it a contextual menu appears letting you copy it, move it, or create a link. To manually create it with the terminal, just [follow Huey's steps](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/210/3).

Answer (score 4):

To create a symbolic link from `/home/huey/galactica` to `/usr/local/pegasus`, meaning that the `galactica` directory in the home folder points to the `pegasus` folder:

```
ln -s /home/huey/galactica /usr/local/pegasus
```