# How can I use multiple folders as library sources in Music (noise)?

Tags: music

I would like to have Music (`noise`) use multiple folders as sources. Is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Essentially, the official answer is that you cannot.

But, there is a workaround - you can use symlinks to trick Music into loading files from multiple folders.

For example, you can create a folder in your external hard drive and then [create a link](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/209/how-can-i-create-a-symbolic-link) to it in `~/Music`.

Noise will be none the wiser, and will show all of your music from multiple locations without issue.

On my system I've chosen to keep my music folder clear of symlinks, so I've instead created a folder called merged music, and placed links to the music folder and other locations where I've stored music files. This way I can fine tune my library in other apps without causing any issue with duplicates.